# Migrating report server database from 2008R2 to 2016 while reporting service is running on SQL2014

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2014

I have SQL reporting service running on SQL 2014 version while reporting database is configured on SQL 2008R2. I am planning to migrate SQL 2008R2 to SQL 2016 so I'll move report server database to new 2016 server while reporting service will be continue to run on SQL 2014. Would there be any issue/concerns if report server database is running on SQL 2016 while reporting service is running SQL 2014?

Comment: The only thing I would suggest is to set the compatibility level of the reports databases to 2014

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following document for SQL Server 2014: [Create a Report Server Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/create-a-report-server-database-ssrs-configuration-manager?view=sql-server-2014) states that it is not supported.

SQL Server is used to host the report server databases. The SQL Server Database Engine instance can be a local or remote instance. The following are the supported versions of SQL Server Database Engine that can be used to host the report server databases:
SQL Server 2014
SQL Server 2012
SQL Server 2008 R2
SQL Server 2008
SQL Server 2005

Comment: Thanks. I did testing by moving report server database to SQL 2016 version and added into AlwaysOn group while reporting services running on SQL 2014 and seems like it is running fine. Will there be any concerns?

Comment: Most probably it will run fine, but you are in a not supported scenario. Most organizations prohibits using not supported scenarios. You are on your own if something breaks.